# How to use hex to represent char in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a c# code, I want to transfer it to javascript. How can I use hex to represent char in js?

the c# code is:

```
s = s.Replace('\r', Convert.ToChar(0x0141));
```

where `s` is string.

Comment: Use `String.fromCharCode`

Comment: [`^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent function should be [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), so for your case it would be:

```
s = s.replace(/\r/g, String.fromCharCode(0x0141));
```

Note use `'\r'` if you only want to replace the first line break. `/\r/g` will replace all line breaks